# call a jquery method on page submit with multiple iframes

Tags: jquery

I have multiple iframes in a page .The inner most one has a jquery attached to it.I need to call a function from the inner most iframe when the page submits.The script i am using now is not intiating the call.

```
$(iframe).parents('form').submit(function() {
    disableDesignMode(iframe, true);
});
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: now you know why iframes are evil :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do:

```
$(form).submit(function() {
    disableDesignMode($(this).children('iframe'), true);
});
```

Comment: can you please explain what this do?